# Possible to auto resize view to be as large as possible upon rotation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have the following set up when the phone is in portrait orientation:

[image]

When I rotate the phone to landscape, I'd like for view1 to resize itself proportionally so as much of it fits on the screen as possible like below:

[image]

I know how to do this manually with code, but I'm wondering is there some kind of auto setting that I can put so the view will know to lay itself out this way whenever the phone is rotated or whenever the view controller is presented in either landscape or portrait orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. define an [`autoresizingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) for your view; or,
2. define [AutoLayout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You do not specify how you create your view, whether in Interface Builder or programmatically.

If you use Interface Builder, just click on your view. If you are not using Auto Layout go to the "Size inspector", and set there graphically the appropriate springs (see image below).

If you use, Auto Layout, then go to Editor/Pin and pin the leading/trailing/top/bottom spaces to superview. Auto Layout may seem a bit tricky to get right at first. You can have a check at http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1.

If you create the view programmatically, the same result can be attained by setting the view's `autoresizingMask` property or adding constraints to it.

This is how you can make a view adapt its bounds to its superview's:

```
NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_subview);

[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[_subview]-16-|"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_subview]-0-|"
                                         options: 0
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:views]];
```

Notice how I also specify a fixed padding (-16-) or no padding at all (-0-).

You could also need calling

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

to avoid possible constraint conflicts (depending on the autoresizingmasks that can be associated to the views).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to add an example of how it could be accomplished with constraints?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically?

Comment: Yes, sorry I keep forgetting to mention, I do everything programmatically.